# Using python sympy to solve a pde maths question

Tags: python, math, sympy, pde

Hey Guys I am trying to use python sympy to solve a pde maths question. But it returns errors.

```
from sympy import Function, Eq
from sympy.abc import x, t, L, c
from sympy.solvers.pde import pdsolve

f = Function('f')
u = Function('u')(x, t)
uxx = u.diff(x, x)
utt = u.diff(t, t)
eq = Eq(utt, c**2*uxx)

bc1 = Eq(u.subs(x, 0), 0)
bc2 = Eq(u.subs(x, L), 0)
ics = {u.subs(t, 0): f}

sol = pdsolve(eq, u, [bc1, bc2], ics=ics)

sol
```

The errors I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 15
     12 bc2 = Eq(u.subs(x, L), 0)
     13 ics = {u.subs(t, 0): f}
---> 15 sol = pdsolve(eq, u, [bc1, bc2], ics=ics)
     17 sol

File c:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\pde.py:169, in pdsolve(eq, func, hint, dict, solvefun, **kwargs)
    166     solvefun = Function('F')
    168 # See the docstring of _desolve for more details.
--> 169 hints = _desolve(eq, func=func, hint=hint, simplify=True,
    170                  type='pde', **kwargs)
    171 eq = hints.pop('eq', False)
    172 all_ = hints.pop('all', False)

File c:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\deutils.py:232, in _desolve(eq, func, hint, ics, simplify, prep, **kwargs)
    229 if not hints['default']:
    230     # classify_ode will set hints['default'] to None if no hints match.
    231     if hint not in allhints and hint != 'default':
--> 232         raise ValueError("Hint not recognized: " + hint)
    233     elif hint not in hints['ordered_hints'] and hint != 'default':
    234         raise ValueError(string + str(eq) + " does not match hint " + hint)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

How should I modify my code? Please explain you answers. Thanks

Comment: Does the API of `dsolve` accept boundary and initial conditions?

Comment: Please show the full error message, Thanks.  (You/we need to know where you are trying to do some sort of join/concatenate with a string.  And why?)

Comment: I didn't see any example ```dsolve``` accept boundary and initial conditions in the document for pde.......

Comment: OK. I will modify my post and show the full error message.

Comment: Please write the following line in this way: `eq = Eq(utt, c**2 * uxx)` (* spaced). I'm afraid it might be thinking that `*uxx` is the list deconstructor instead of the multiplication operator.